# Error "The connection was reset" after updating PHP code on server with git

Tags: debian, apache-http-server, git, vmware-workstation

Using Windows 7 Pro HOST, VMware Workstation 12 Player v12.5.0 build-4352439, with Debian v7.11 GUEST, Apache v2.2.2. Browser is Waterfox 64bit v53.0.

```
cat /etc/debian_version
7.11

apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Dec 23 2014 22:48:29

git --version
git version 2.9.3
```

**PROBLEM:**

After pushing the changes in PHP code to the server bare repo, which checks out into a worktree directory, I get the following error when reloading a page:

```
The connection was reset
```

If I execute

```
"sudo service apache2 reload"
```

the webpage loads fine again...

**QUESTION:**

What should I do to avoid the need to reload apache each time I do PHP code change & git push?

Comment: What is "the server code"? Static files, or some server-side (e.g. PHP) scripts?

Comment: On server-side PHP scripts are changed.